# TexStudio gives 'Could not start command' with my custom build script

Tags: errors, compiling, texstudio

I have a custom build script `build.command` that runs through the build steps necessary to convert my LaTex scripts into a .pdf (e.g. makeglossaries and so on). The script works fine. However when I try and get it to run in TexStudio it complains, saying: `Error: Could not start the command: /Users/jackaidley/Documents/report/build.command "report"`. However, if I copy and paste from that to the Terminal and run the command then it works fine so I don't understand what the problem could be?

I have set it to run by modifying the pdfLaTex run command to `?a)build.command %`.

This on Mac OS X 10.8.4 with TexStudio 2.4.

Comment: It would help to list `build.command` here so we can see what is being done.

Comment: It's not getting as far as running `build.command` so what's in it makes no difference, does it? Actually, though, that's given me an idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it wasn't working was that the `build.command` file didn't contain the first line `#!/bin/bash`. I'm not sure why it would work from the command line but via TexStudio but there you go.

Thanks to Sean Allred's comment for giving me the inspiration to try this.

Comment: Note that if one were to say `#!/bin/env python` instead as the first line, you could write a `python` script to process (eg compile) your document.  That first line is called a shebang, and it tells *other* programs what kind of script it is.  If you're already running `bash` (via Terminal), then `bash` will just do what `bash` does.