# Run custom commands after TeXstudio finishes building pdf

Tags: texstudio

[TeXstudio 2.10.4, Win7]
I would like to be able to run a custom CLI command (batch, script, or executable) after the document build process has completed.  Since the build process is a chain of commands, I think I should be able to do this, but am confused by the tags used (like `txs://compile`) that are in the Configure TeXstudio -> Build screen.
Anyone able to suggest how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tags `txs:///...` references commands. You can check the tag of a command in it's tooltip (see attached image). Just create a user command for your CLI command and add it to the compile command.

For further details see [Section 1.3.1 Advanced configuration of the build system](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#SECTION02a) in the user manual.

*(image updated)*

[image]

Comment: Thanks Tim but its not quite working.  Like your example, I'm also using a `.vbs` and I've configured my TeXstudio as per your diagram.  However, I'm getting an  `Error: Could not start the command: ...` message, similar to [Jack](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124918/texstudio-gives-could-not-start-command-with-my-custom-build-script), but since I'm using Win there is no need for a 'shebang'.  I've added `cscript ` into the command definition, but hasn't helped.  Any ideas?

Comment: I've also tried changing the characters `/` to `\ ` and `\\ `, but it is still not working.

Comment: I tried running an arbitrary, but benign executable and it worked.  So I'm guessing it doesn't like `.vbs` scripts or doesn't know how to handle them and needs a wrapper.

Comment: Fixed.  Need to have `"C:\Windows\System32\cscript.exe" ` before the  `vbs` script path & name.  Note that `cscript` must be enclosed in its own set of quotation marks.  So the full command became:  `"C:\Windows\System32\cscript.exe" "C:\My Folder\my sub-folder\myscript.vbs"`. (Also, the slashes have to be the normal Win backshash `\ `.)

Comment: If you want to pass parameters to your script, you need to format the command a little different.  Use: `cmd /C "C:\Windows\System32\cscript.exe myscript.vbs %"`.  The `%` is a TeXstudio symbol for "[filename of the root document for of current document without extension](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#SECTION02)".