# TeXstudio; 'could not start the command' for custom command running bash script

Tags: macros, texstudio, scripts, bash

Edit: **solved**.

Solution: [RTFM](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/master/utilities/manual/usermanual_en.html#SECTION02a).

I.e. as [Schoekling suggested](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/591252/208725), the manual states:

*"Each user command has a name with a pattern :, e.g. user0:User Command 0. The command id has to be unique and must not contain spaces. In advanced mode, you can reference it using txs:///"<command id>. "*

---

I'm using Mendeley to export .bib files, and  am trying to run a shell script to remove the 'abstract' entries and running `biber --tool --validate-model` before running biber:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
biber --tool --configfile=bibtex_files/remabs.conf bibtex_files/examplebib.bib
biber --tool --validate-datamodel bibtex_files/examplebib_bibertool.bib
```

The command runs just fine from the shell and **also in TeXstudio when using Tools > User > {commandname}**.

However, running as part of the build config, I get the error:

`Error: Could not start the command: jrb2:///biberprepare`

I'm running:

```
- TeXstudio 3.1.1
- texlive/pdfTeX; Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020)
- biber version 2.16 rev. 57273
- OS: Ubuntu 20.04 kernel 5.8.0-48-generic
```

My TeXstudio Meta Commands are configured as follows:

(relevant lines in case the images won't load)

```
Default Compiler: txs:///pdflatex | jrb2:///biberprepare | txs:///biber | txs:///pdflatex | txs:///pdflatex
Build & View: txs:///compile | txs:///view
Default Bibliography Tool: txs:///biber
```

```
User Commands:
First entry field | Second text entry field
jrb2:biberprepare | biberprepare.sh
```

All 'repeat' options are disabled.

[image: TeXstudio 'metacommands' configuration 1/2]

[image: TeXstudio 'metacommands' configuration 2/2]

I don't think the commands section is relevant per se, but it could be:
[image: TexStudio 'commands' configuration]

The directory structure is as follows:

```
textest
     +----biberprepare.sh
     +----bibtex_files
     |    +----examplebib.bib
     +----chapters
     |    +----introduction.tex
     +----figures
     |    +----titlepage
     |    |    +----example1.svg
     |    +----introduction
     |         +----example2.svg
     +----introduction.tex
     +----maintest.aux
     +----maintest.bcf
     +----maintest.log
     +----maintest.out
     +----maintest.pdf
     +----maintest.run.xml
     +----maintest.synctex.gz
     +----maintest.tex
     +----remabs.conf
     +----svg-inkscape
     |    +----example1_svg-tex.pdf_tex
     |    +----example1_svg-tex.pdf
     +----titlepage.tex
```

What could be the cause of this?

Some things I tried:

- A potential solution proposed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/286712/run-custom-commands-after-texstudio-finishes-building-pdf) suggested OP forgot the shebang. However this is not the case here.
- I thought that maybe the script needed execute permission, so I ran `chmod +x biberprepare.sh` -> to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in [the manual (sec. 3.1)](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/master/utilities/manual/usermanual_en.html#SECTION02a) the left field under 'User Commands' has the format `<command id>:<display name>` and not something like `<group>:<command id>`. To call the command, you have to reference the command ID, not the display name by using

```
txs:///jrb2
```

in the chain.

[The answer to the question you linked](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/286816/163512) illustrates how to reference the command, too:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I recall looking in the manual. Not sure why I looked over that part.